# How to get values from Object

Tags: javascript, object, filter

I want to filter a table Demandtable according to the the filtercondition given below.I get the answer in the result Variable which is not null but I am unable to fetch the rows from the result.

```
var filtercondition = {"location": "Delhi", "product": "ScrewMachine"};
var result = Demandtable.filter(search, filtercondition);

function search(Demandtable){
  return Object.keys(this).every((key) => Demandtable[key] === this[key]);
}
```

The above code works but I don't know how to get Values from the result Object. How can I get them?

Comment: Do you want to get all the values or search for 1?

Comment: Can you please show Demandtable?

Comment: Your question is not clear. In this case it will throw an error regarding `Demandtable`

Comment: You mean `Object.values(result)`?

Comment: @TamDc ES6 only though. Could instead use `Object.keys(result).map(function(key){ return result[key];})`. If that's what is being asked.

Comment: var Demandtable = [{"location": "Delhi", "product": "ScrewMachine","date":new Date(2010,01,01),"Demand":101}, 
            var Demandtable = [{"location": "Delhi", "product": "ScrewMachine","date":new Date(2010,01,01),"Demand":101}, 
             {"location": "Delhi", "product": "ScrewMachine","date":new Date(2010,02,01),"Demand":102},
             {"location": "Kolkatta", "product": "ScrewMachine","date":new Date(2011,01,01),"Demand":103},
            ];

Comment: This is the Demandtable I want the rows from the result .

Comment: Object.values(result) give me the following   [Object object] [Object object]  and not the actual row from the table Demandtable

Comment: @priyakalashi Do you just want to print it? Because ` [Object object] [Object object]` is what you get when you convert an object to a string

Comment: Object.keys(result).map(function(key){ return result[key];}). This gives me error saying 'Cannot convert undefined or NULL to object

Comment: @priyakalashi So? Do you just want to print it? Because ` [Object object] [Object object]` is what you get when you convert an object to a string

Comment: I want the values in the Object (result )that is returned.

Comment: @priyakalashi First of all, `result` is an array and not an object and also I still don't understand the problem here? `console.log(result)` works for me

Comment: thanks for your reply. In the console I cant see the actual display of the row in numbers something like this as a row "Delhi",ScrewMachine",Date(2010,02,01),102. I can see [Object object]

Comment: @priyakalashi Try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))`

Comment: thanks Sir it worked .

Comment: I can see the result with JSON.stringify(result) but how to get the actual values of the columns in the array result as [i][j]. is it not possible.May be I am wrong somewhere